# AWS Lambda recursive invocation works too good?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are using SQS queues for asynchronous messages and need Lambda functions to do some transformations and logging of the messages on certain queues.
After a lot of research I have decided I will go for a recursive Lambda function as the messages are not really critical and going through using SNS or SWF in between seems overly complicated (and I'm hoping Amazon soon will add a Lambda trigger for SQS).

The maximum execution duration per request for a Lambda function is supposed to be 300 seconds (5 minutes) so I figured to invoke the Lambda over-and-over and then have a Cloudwatch trigger set to 5 minutes to re-trigger the Lambda for another 5 minute run.

However the Lambda just keep running (without the Cloudwatch trigger). I tested it yesterday and was surprised when it kept going past the 300 seconds and now it has been running for over 24 hours...

So, question is, how come it keeps running?
I assume that each time I invoke it Lambda considers it a new request. As the SQS long-poll time-out is 20 seconds and I invoke also after time-out (in case of no new message) it keeps on going as new requests, right?

Also, if I add the Cloudwatch trigger at 5 minutes interval, will I then start multiple instances of the same Lambda function?

(And yes, I am aware I am being billed for the run time but it is still cheaper than an EC2 instance even running 24/7)

**EDIT**:
Adding Cloudwatch logs that shows the invokation and recursive running:

> 15:48:22
>   **START** RequestId: ee3f71df-b001-11e6-a0d6-bffc6057d58c Version: $LATEST
>
> 15:48:42
>   2016-11-21T15:48:42.188Z    ee3f71df-b001-11e6-a0d6-bffc6057d58c    Calling again... and again...
>
> 15:48:42
>   END RequestId: ee3f71df-b001-11e6-a0d6-bffc6057d58c
>
> 15:48:42
>   REPORT RequestId: ee3f71df-b001-11e6-a0d6-bffc6057d58c  Duration: 20115.93 ms   Billed Duration: 20200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 37 MB
>
> 15:48:42
>   **START** RequestId: fa443a44-b001-11e6-bea9-4fe2d7bd8fe7 Version: $LATEST
>
> 15:49:02
>   2016-11-21T15:49:02.386Z    fa443a44-b001-11e6-bea9-4fe2d7bd8fe7    Calling again... and again...
>
> 15:49:02
>   END RequestId: fa443a44-b001-11e6-bea9-4fe2d7bd8fe7
>
> 15:49:02
>   REPORT RequestId: fa443a44-b001-11e6-bea9-4fe2d7bd8fe7  Duration: 20156.93 ms   Billed Duration: 20200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 37 MB
>
> 15:49:02
>   **START** RequestId: 0647caad-b002-11e6-adc9-73ebc92281fd Version: $LATEST
>
> 15:49:22
>   2016-11-21T15:49:22.601Z    0647caad-b002-11e6-adc9-73ebc92281fd    Calling again... and again...
>
> 15:49:22
>   END RequestId: 0647caad-b002-11e6-adc9-73ebc92281fd
>
> 15:49:22
>   REPORT RequestId: 0647caad-b002-11e6-adc9-73ebc92281fd  Duration: 20179.49 ms   Billed Duration: 20200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 37 MB

Comment: What do you mean when you say recursive? Is your Lambda function invoking more instances of itself? It sounds like you have runaway recursion causing many instances of your function to be running.

Comment: Yes, it is calling itself. There are three possibilities for the script to complete, the successful processing of a message, an error while processing the message or the 20 second time-out of SQS poll. In each of the three scenarios the Lambda calls itself again before "dying" thus it is re-invoking itself in a new Request so it should only be one instance simultaneously.

Comment: As you can see it gets a new RequestId for each "START" and thus it will never hit the 300 seconds as the max poll time-out is only 20 seconds.
I just want to confirm my theory so I don't end up with multiple Lambda functions in parallell...

Comment: If it is invoking a new instance of itself every time it is complete, then you will always have an instance of the function running. I'm not sure why you are surprised by that. Adding a CloudWatch event trigger to this function would then result in multiple instances running concurrently because you would have the function itself creating new invocations as well as CloudWatch creating new invocations.

Comment: I guess the "surprise" is that it is the Request time-out that is 300 seconds and not the Lambda function itself. From the documentation I'd thought that using the re-invokation it would've still self-destructed after 300 seconds. This is a good thing though as I now have inadvertently created what I actually needed without having to trigger it through Cloudwatch every 5 minutes...

Comment: In this case, invocation == request. Each invocation is a new request, which creates an entirely new instance of the Lambda function with a new timeout. (I'm being a bit simplistic and disregarding Lambda container reuse, but that is not really relevant to this issue)

Comment: Well, thank you! That pretty much answering the question!

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say in your comments, your function is self-invoking, then adding a trigger will cause new *chains* of lambdas to launch every few minutes. As it stands, your current function should run forever (until a crash).

If you want to have something like flock safety in lambda, you can do a few things:

1. create a trigger lambda that is invoked by cloudwatch. All this lambda would do is check an expiring key somewhere (either S3, SQS, or elasticache can be used for this) to see if another lambda was invoked in the last X minutes. If not, launch a new copy.
2. remove the recursion in your lambda if the queue is empty.
3. keep both in, but only allow a maxmimum recursion depth. This is slightly different than #2 in that during longer runs (IE: when you have data in SQS), you could set it up in such a way that multiple lambdas are running simultaneously waiting on an empty queue. However, it also lowers the chance of a minor error spawning infinite lambdas.

Independent of this, I think having a recursive lambda with no hard cap on recursion depth sounds super dangerous.